# Deploying Go 1.6 web app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy my web app to elastic beanstalk but it appears to only support Go 1.4 rather than Go 1.6. Is there a way to get a custom image?

The reason I want 1.6 is because it supports vendoring and my web app depends on 3rd party packages.

Comment: You can create your own custom AMI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice would be to use [**docker**](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/).

Here are the steps to deploy your application to Elastic Beanstalk:

1. Choose the **Generic Docker** platform when creating a new environment.
2. Put a file named `Dockerfile` in your project root with the following content:

---

```
FROM golang:1.6.2-onbuild
EXPOSE 80
```

---

3. Add a [**canonical import path**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jVFkZTcYbNLaTxXD9OcGfn7vYv5hWtPx9--lTx1gPMs/edit) to your `main.go`. For example, if your package name is `my/package` the first line of `main.go` should be `package main // import "my/package"`
4. Make your application **listen on port 80**
5. Deploy!

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far. I think uploading a binary file called application is the best option.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting the error: '/var/app/current/application: /var/app/current/application: cannot execute binary file'. I'm compiling my app on OSX Yosemite. Is that the issue?

Comment: @ChrisW is this issue (error executing binary file) still relevant ?

Comment: @JohnSPerayil This issue was for a previous version of this answer. It is no longer relevant.

Comment: Docker is great as long as you don't use the aws-sdk-go library which requires Go 1.5+ since Docker (within AWS) is limited to Go 1.4

Comment: @MTarantini No It's not. There is a difference between the preconfigured docker images (limited to Go 1.4) and generic docker.

Comment: @fl0cke Good call. What would you say is the advantage of Docker over using a Native Go platform?

Comment: @fl0cke Wouldn't they both? What is specifically an advantage of Docker over a Native Go platform?

Comment: @MTarantini Well, It doesn't depend on amazon maintaining the AMI. You can run anything you want in a docker container. Including versions of Go not supported by elastic beanstalk.