# How do you install Go dependencies when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application that's split across a few different files and I'm having trouble deploying it. I've followed [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html), but I'm getting the following:

```
application.go:7:5: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/handlers" in any of:
```

I assume I need to install the libraries I'm using in the `$GOPATH` as part of the deployment process, but I don't know how to do that and haven't found any examples of it. Using the Procfile seems promising, but all of my searches keep leading me to Heroku resources.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103362/deploying-go-1-6-web-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 2):

You could use a vendoring tool to store all your dependencies within a vendor folder.

I use [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor).

```
Steps:
 1. go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor
 2. cd $GOPATH/yourProject
 3. govendor init
 4. govendor add +external
```

Now the directory 'yourProject' can be build independently on any machine provided it is in $GOPATH.

**Note :** Requires Go 1.6+ or 1.5 with GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1.

**Edit :** As per [fl0cke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125099/fl0cke)'s comment. If Elastic Beanstalk only supports Go 1.4, the possible options are :

- Cross compile a binary and deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk.
- Create a [custom AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html) with Go 1.6+ installed..
- Create a [Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/) Image as per [fl0cke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36108460/2285935).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and was able to fix it by using the [eb client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html).

Just to cover the basics:

1. The name of your main file should be `application.go`.
2. Make sure your app is listening on port 5000.
3. You'll need a `Procfile` in the main root with

   ```
   web: bin/application
   ```
4. You'll need a `Buildfile` with

   ```
   make: ./build.sh
   ```
5. And finally you'll need a build.sh file with

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   # Stops the process if something fails
   set -xe

   # All of the dependencies needed/fetched for your project.
   # This is what actually fixes the problem so that EB can find your dependencies. 
   # FOR EXAMPLE:
   go get "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

   # create the application binary that eb uses
   GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bin/application -ldflags="-s -w"
   ```

Then if you run eb deploy (after creating your inital eb replository), it should work. I think you can get the same results by then zipping your `application.go`, `Procfile`, `Buildfield`, and `build.sh` script and loading that into the Elastic Beanstalk console, but I haven't tried it.

I wrote a whole tutorial for deploying a Gin application on EB [here](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/07/30/gin-elastic-beanstalk-and-memcache/). The section specifically on deploying with Elastic Beanstalk is [here](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/07/30/gin-elastic-beanstalk-and-memcache/#deploying-with-elastic-beanstalk).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me as of mid-2019. The gist is to compile *locally* and upload your binary. Run this from your project root:

```
GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -o bin/application
```

Then include this binary in your application zip that you upload to the EB console.